# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError 'form' is undefined in Python Flask

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

I am making an application on Google app engine using Python Flask and I am new to Python Flask , learning new things everyday. I am using the jinja2 template with flask it works fine on all the pages but it does not recognize 
`{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` 
in my signup page for users and throws an exception

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError`

Here is my Signup.html code

```
    `<!-- This is my page -->
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %} Sign up | Eventus {% endblock %}
    {% block style_block %}
        <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/css/social-buttons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">  
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container theme-showcase">
    <div class="row">


            <h3><center>Sign Up Uscore</center></h3><br><br>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form id="signup" class="navbar-form form-inline" action="{{ url_for('signup_action') }}" method="post" >

                <fieldset>
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="control-label">{{ form.example_name.label }}</div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        {{ form.example_name|safe }}
                        {% if form.example_name.errors %}
                        <ul class="errors">
                            {% for error in form.example_name.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="control-label">{{ form.example_description.label }}</div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        {{ form.example_description|safe }}
                        {% if form.example_description.errors %}
                        <ul class="errors">
                            {% for error in form.example_description.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Example"/>
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>


                <!-- <input type="text" name="username" value="{{username}}" placeholder="your username" class="form-control"></input><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="{{email}}" placeholder="your email" class="form-control"></input><br><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="{{password}}" placeholder="your password" class="form-control"></input><br><br>
                <input type="password" name="confpassword" value="" placeholder="retype password" class="form-control" /><br><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="" class="form-control" style="width: 15px; height: 12px;"/> Remember me
                <a href="" class="pull-right">forgot password</a><br><br><br> 
                <input type="submit" name="signup_submit" value"Sign Up" class="btn btn-success" />
                Already a Member<a href="" > Sign in </a> --> 

            </form>



        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-google-plus" href="/signin/google/">
                <i class="icon icon-google-plus"></i>
                    Sign in with Google
        </a>    
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-google-plus" href="/signin/googleoauth/">
                <i class="icon icon-google-plus"></i>
                    Sign in with Google plus
        </a>    
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-facebook" href="/signin/facebook/">
                <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
                    Sign in with Facebook
        </a>    
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-twitter" href="/signin/twitter/">
                <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>
                    Sign in with Twitter
        </a>    


        </div>


    </div>


    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Here is the Error I get on my page

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 101, in dispatch_request
return view_func(**req.view_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 149, in runcall
return func(*args, **kw)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/views.py", line 149, in dispatch_request
return meth(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/application/views.py", line 154, in get
return flask.render_template('signup.html')
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/lib/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/flask_vir/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-production/uscore/src/application/templates/signup.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "base.html" %}
UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

Please let me know where I am writing the code wrong, do I need to make a seaperate file for social login or I need to do some settings as per google app engine.

Comment: what does your handler look like? Are you passing 'form' to the template?

Comment: yes I have made forms.py and defined the form as per my models.py and then Put the form in my signup.html template but it throws the error at very first declaration of for i.e.

    {{form.hidden_tag()}}

Comment: Greg This is the handler I defined 
    `jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join('.', 'templates')))`

Comment: could you update your code with your view function please?

Comment: Sorry I missed the 'flask' tag and assumed webapp2. By 'handler' I mean the python code that renders the template.

Comment: thanks Greg initially you were right about looking up the handler, I was commiting the typo in the render_template method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error you are getting is :

```
    jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
    UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

you might have to try using forms. See if that works

Comment: thanks ankit the error was due to a typo that I mispelled as 'forms' but I had to spell it 'form'